# Outgoing Calls Are Not Recording

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-api

here is the code to make a call

```
function dialCall(num)
{
    params = {"phoneNumber": num, "record":"record-on-answer", "callStatus":"call", "callerId": "<?php echo $call_id; ?>", "tenantId":"<?php echo $pusher_channel; ?>"};
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}
```

The calls are being connected successfully and the conversations are normal. My problem is it wont record the outgoing phone calls.
Anyone here who uses `Twilio.Device.connect`to make phonecalls? Can you please help me make the record work? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

below is a screen shot of the twilio console showing that the calls are successfully made.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Can you post the TwiML that you're giving to Twilio with we request your TwiML Application URL?

To record both legs of your call you need to make sure that you are [including the `record` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record) in the `<Dial>` verb in that TwiML:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+15556666666" record="record-from-answer">
        <Number>+15555555555</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using the Javascript SDK  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect to make phone calls...

Comment: The answer still applies. There is no way from the JS SDK to tell Twilio to record the call.  That happens by specifying the attribute as shown above.